# Allow access to windows service hosted WCF services only to one ASP MVC app in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, azure

I have:

- WCF services hosted in Windows service on my Azure virtual machine.
- ASP MVC web app hosted in Azure App service which connects to my WCF
  services.

How can I make WCF services accessible only by ASP MVC app? In other words: only ASP MVC app is allowed to consume my WCF services.

Sorry for not having any code examples but WCF security is a very big topic and most examples I found cover only Windows domain WCF authorization. Nothing specific to my case.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to my problem.

In WCF proxy class derived from  `ClientBase<T>` I overrode base constructor with user credentials in PC where my WCF services are running.

```
base.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "localhost\\myUsername";
base.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "myPassword";
```

in WCF service app.config:

```
<security mode="Transport">
          <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
</security>
```

So now my services require credentials from any consumer.